# C# Excluding elements from array.sum

Tags: c#, arrays, sum

What is the cleanest way to exclude an element in an array when summing?

**Example:**

```
array.sum(exclude index 5);
```

Comment: Remove the item from the array?

Comment: @ChristmasUnicorn: Or just subtract it after summing.

Answer (score 11):

Rather than trying to build a temporary array or *skip over* that value, it might be faster to just subtract the value of `array[5]` from the sum:

```
array.Sum() - array[5]
```

Answer (score 5):

If you insist on using LINQ for this, then you can do it using `Take` and `Skip`. Assuming the item at index 5 is to be ignored, you need the values at indexes 0-4, so you take the first 5 items, then you concat that with the items after the 5th index, so you skip the first 6 items.

```
array.Take(5).Concat(array.Skip(6)).Sum();
```

The better solution, as Matt Burland points out in a comment and [Mike Christensen](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20665640/467172) points out in his answer, is to sum the whole list and just subtract the single value you want to ignore.

Comment: You could also do: `array.Select((x, i) => i == 5 ? 0 : x).Sum();`

Comment: @SebastianPiu Yup, another valid way - though I still believe Mike's answer provides the most proper method.